# SPFile.CopyTo() vs RootFolder.Files.Add()

Tags: document-library, spfile

I've been looking for method of copying a file or folder from one document library to a number of other libraries with the same name in each subsite for a particular site collection. What needs to happen is when a folder or file is added on one site it needs to be copied to all other sites in the collection.

I've seen that the `SPFile` class has a `CopyTo()` function but most of the answers regarding copying files I have come across suggest using

```
    byte[] fileBytes = item1.File.OpenBinary();
    string destUrl = lib2.RootFolder.Url + "/" + item1.File.Name;
    SPFile destFile = lib2.RootFolder.Files.Add(destUrl, fileBytes, true);
```

Which is the correct method for copying a file or folder structure within a site collection?

Regards
~Donald

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SharePoint has great built in methods to copy or move documents across sub-sites or lists within the same site collection.
You can use SPFile.MoveTo or SPFile.CopyTo.
You can even move whole folders and their contents with the SPFolder.MoveTo method.
Very nice. **Unfortunately, these do not work across site collections.**

where as use of RootFolder.Files.Add is something like below:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://yoursiteurl"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {                  
        using (FileStream fs = (new FileInfo("c:\\somepath")).OpenRead())
        {
            SPList list = web.Lists["test"];
           
            //add metadata
            Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
            ht.Add("testcol", "myfile");
            ht.Add("vti_title", "mytitle");

            SPFile destfile = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(strDocName, fs, ht, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically you're saying for my example above CopyTo is perfectly acceptable however if I were using multiple site collections then the byte streaming method is preferable.

Comment: Yes, exactly for your requirement you are good to go with CopyTo.