# Errror: The field you are trying to update may be read only

Tags: web-part, picture-library

When adding a new item programmatically to picture library I'm facing this issue:

> The field you are trying to update may be read only

Here is my code

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://SiteName"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    if (fuImages.HasFile)
                    {
                        StreamImage = fuImages.PostedFile.InputStream;
                    }
                    SPList list = web.Lists["Listname"];
                    SPFile file = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fuImages.FileName, StreamImage);
                    SPListItem itemToAdd = file.Item;

                    itemToAdd["Title"] = title;
                    itemToAdd["Description"] = desc;

                    itemToAdd.Update();
                    list.Update();
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: What type of issue? Please elaborate your question that someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are getting issue while updating metadata for image.

To add meta data like title and description you can use hashtable in list.RootFolder.Files.Add

For example you can check this link: [SPFile.CopyTo() vs RootFolder.Files.Add()](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78426/spfile-copyto-vs-rootfolder-files-add)